# Update SQL entry using textbox values on button click event using C# WPF

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf

I have a WPF form with a button.

There is a textbox under the button and I want the .text to go into a list box

Comment: "Not performing the desired result"?  Your SQL doesn't look valid.  What is the current result?  Does the app crash / throw an exception?

Comment: You should really consider databinding that textbox text if its a permanent feature of this app you are writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for your update command should be something like this, note that you haven't mentioned the name of the table in the database which is storing the data, so I've just called it `ButtonTable`:

```
...
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [ButtonTable] SET [TimesClicked] = @nm WHERE [ButtonName] = @buttonName;";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@buttonName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = "Button1";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@nm", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox1.Text;
...
```

Also, I recommend specifying the type of your parameters as in the above sample.

Comment: If we're going to use a parameter for `TimesClicked`, we should also use one for `ButtonName`.